# How to map a @ManyToOne association to the result of an SQL query

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, join, many-to-one

We are working on a migration project and we are migrating from HBM files to annotations.

We are facing repeated column mapping issue when I try to set a value on a property, which basically is an instance of the same class.

```
public class Salary{

    // All the below are coming from lookup table like empLookUp, MonthLookup, 
    // YearLookup, CurrencyLookUp and they are joined using their primary key

    private int empId;
    private int month;
    private int year;
    private String currency;

    // Issue here: previousMonthSalary actually needs to be populated when the 
    // Salary is loaded, but for previous month. How do I achieve this.

    private Salary previousMonthSalary;

}
```

How to map the `previousMonthSalary`?

Comment: Post your real code (with the annotations, and without invalid stuff like `Public`), and post the complete stack trace of the exception.

Comment: Please explain or show what the problem is. An exception or the wrong result,..

Answer (score 5):

Most likely, you need to use the `@JoinFormula` annotation:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinFormula("(" +
    "SELECT s.id " +
    "FROM salary s " +
    "WHERE s.empId = empId " +
    "AND CASE WHEN month = 1 THEN s.year + 1 = year AND s.month = 12 ELSE s.year = year AND s.month - 1 = month END "
")")
private Salary previousMonthSalary;
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope the use of lazy fetch in previousMonthSalary variable will resolve your issue.

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=fetchType.Lazy) 
private Salary previousMonthSalary;
```